# Tense in a sentence

Tags: tense, present-tense

Context: "I never imagined this letter accounts for the events of that evening."

The sentence is taken from a written testimony. The author states that she hadn't known a fact until she did an action (read the letter). Since the letter still exists and remains true to her statement (it still accounts for the events of that evening), the author used the present tense for the verb *account*.

In my opinion, the tenses of the sentence don't mix well. I'd rather use the present perfect for *imagine*, and then *account* in the present simple. What do you think, is her suggestion fine, or should the sentence be edited?

Comment: I agree with you. "I never imagined that this letter _might account_ for the events..." would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Even more likely, [*...never imagined it **would...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never+imagined+it+might%2Cnever+imagined+it+would&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnever%20imagined%20it%20might%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnever%20imagined%20it%20would%3B%2Cc0) (Presumably the letter ***did*** account for events once found and examined, so it's not necessary to convey any implications of a "***possible*** explanation". But I certainly wouldn't "correct" a native speaker who used the cited version. It's not *that* "inelegant".

Comment: Did you consider past perfect?  Surely she *now* imagines the contents of the letter as they stand in fact, now that she's become acquainted with the letter's accounts.  The phrasing "I had never imagined..." works with an implication something like "until I learned the truth."  Then again, so does the simple past construction.  That choice might boil down to emphasis, personal taste and dialectic preference.  A present-tense construction (like you suggest) would imply that she *still* doesn't know better at the time of her utterance -- but the author clearly disagrees with that.